# When bitshifting by 16, why is the output different because of different type casting

Tags: java, bit-shift

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        long x = 164997969936395L;
        
        int a = (int)(x >>> 16);
        
        System.out.println(a); //Prints -1777298077

        long b = (x >>> 16);
        
        System.out.println(b); //Prints 2517669219
        
    }
```

Trying to bitshift x by 16 bits, but the output differs depending on whether i use a long or an int, also it seems when i use long the negative signs are always gone.

I've also noticed when using int it really is divided by 2^16 whereas using long it is not, what's happening there?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `2517669219`, which is `x >>> 16`, is narrowed down to an `int`.

`int` can represent values in the range `[-2147483648, 2147483647]`.
`2517669219` is greater than `2147483647`, so [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) happens.